# Failed: can't create session: no servers available: server selection failed: context deadline exceeded

Tags: mongodb, connector

I'm getting an error while trying to use the mongodb for bi connector. I am in the generation stage of the schema of difinição of the file utliznaod the executable mongodrdl. At the moment I'm getting the error below.

I've already made sure that the connection data to my base mongo is correct and I can access my base with other connection tools.

If someone has already had this problem, I would be grateful if they share the solution to the problem.

cmd command executed: `"C:\Arquivos de Programas\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.3\bin\mongodrdl.exe" --host {localhost} --db store --collection avalaible --out schema.drdl`

cmd command executed: `"C:\Arquivos de Programas\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.3\bin\mongodrdl.exe" --host {127.0.0.1} --db store --collection avalaible --out schema.drdl`

error: `Failed: can't create session: no servers available: server selection failed: context deadline exceeded`

installation tutorial I'm following: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-bi-connector/

Answer (score 8):

If you run into this issue with mongosqld itself try adding "/?connect=direct" to the URI, i.e. "mongosqld --mongo-uri "mongodb://192.168.0.28/?connect=direct".  I have a replica set of 1 and ran into that error.

Comment: you saved my life!

Comment: you are best buddy on the earth Robert

Comment: Thanks, that was a tricky one since the connection URI without the connect=direct works just fine for the  mongo client, but some reason mongosqld requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Michel, that error is a typical indication that you either don't have `mongod` running, or if you do, `mongodrdl` is unable to reach it. Check that you indeed have `mongod` running and reachable from the machine where you're running `mongodrdl`.

Also note that `mongodrdl` isn't required to use the BI Connector - there is a feature called 'sampling' that removes the need to first run `mongodrdl`. See https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/schema-configuration/#cached-sampling for more.

Answer (score 1):

In my case similar thing has happened when I'm trying to connect to mongoDB Atlas cluster via **mongodrdl** command provided by mongo documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongodrdl/ .

So make sure you give -ssl in the command if your cluster has ssl enabled otherwise you'll run into same issue. If you don't get any error in console then you should probably got connected.

Comment: So basically `--ssl` has to be included in the command, after with `--host` is specified.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite weird for the error message .
on my case, it was cause by a wrong username & password for specific database.

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap my password in quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `TLSConfig` worked for me, I tried on golang, might be different property name in other languages